# How to draw bonds between departure and arrival atoms correctly in chemfig?

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I tried to draw hydantoin's structure with the code like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{chemfig}
\def\Hv@scale{0.65}
\makeatother
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\foo}{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\foo{#1}}}
\makeatother
\setchemfig{double bond sep = 0.20700 em,   
            fixed length = false,    
            bond offset = 0.18265 em, 
            bond style={line width=0.50pt},
            atom sep = 1.2 em}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\chemfig{*6(-=*6(-O--(-=^[:-30]*5(-[2,2]HN-(=O)-NH-(=O)-))=-)-=-=)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and the output:

[image]

However, I expect to draw something like this:

[image]

The bond is supposed to connect with nitrogen atom not hydrogen. How to adjust the bond between nitrogen atom and carbon atom correctly?
I've tried guanine example in chemfig documentation (page 42) but it didn't work. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. For example I am not expert of the chemical structure :-(...But how must be your image?

Comment: I've updated the question with how the image is supposed to be. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Welcome again and thank you for the addendum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{chemfig}
\def\Hv@scale{0.65}
\makeatother
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\foo}{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\foo{#1}}}
\makeatother
\setchemfig{double bond sep = 0.20700 em,   
            fixed length = false,    
            bond offset = 0.18265 em, 
            bond style={line width=0.50pt},
            atom sep = 1.2 em}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\chemfig{
  *6(
  -=*6(
  -O--
  (-=^[:-30]
  *5(-[,,,2]HN-(=O)-NH-(=O)-NH)
  )
  =-
  )-=-=
  )
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly.

Comment: @lafuannaufal, you are very welcome.

Comment: @modnar Please what is the error? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano, according to the documentation of `chemfig` (Section 7, I believe), the arrival and departure atoms are supposed to be specify by [,,d,a].

Comment: @modnar Thank you very much...I have upvoted 5 min ago :-)